# Bootstrap - hover one change another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know how to do this: I want change color `class = "dropdown-toggle"` when I hover `.dropdown-menu li`

`.dropdown-menu li:hover` (or `li > a`) (`~` or `+` or `>`) `.dropdown-toggle {...}` - its not working

Can I do it in CSS?

My code follows below:

```
<li class = "dropdown"> 
    <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"> Lorem ipsum</a>
    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">    
        <li><a href="video.html"> Hellooooo </a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Blablabla </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: + is for next sibling, but css3 has no previous sibling selector. So try JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do here with pure CSS is

```
ul li.dropdown:hover > a {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uAct6/)

Over here, am selecting the anchor tag which is a direct child to `li.dropdown` on hover of the `.dropdown` which holds the sub `ul`

Comment: Your workaround will work but it will get all the content inside .dropdown behaving like only the dropdown-menu should. Maybe it would be better to use JavaScript.

Comment: @Hoijof it depends, I provided the best he can do with pure CSS, sometimes, it happens that users want to achieve some sort of effect but they don't have access to other files but CSS

Comment: That's what you say is totally true, I just wanted to warn him about the misbehavior that this workaround may cause.

Comment: Mr. Alien -
 You are the best! ;) Thanks a lot! 

Hoijof thanks! In JS I can do a lot of but I'm always happy when I try to do something only in CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.

If there was a way to do it, it would be in the CSS selectors specs, either CSS 2 or 3

- [CSS 3 Selectors Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)
- [CSS 2 Selectors Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

You'll have to use js to do that.

EDIT: You could use the workaround that @Mr. Alien put in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use Jquery for this.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4fn9/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var menuItem = $('.dropdown-menu li');
   var itemToChange = $('.dropdown-toggle');
   menuItem.on('mouseenter', function(){
     itemToChange.css('background-color', 'red');
   });
   menuItem.on('mouseleave', function(){
      itemToChange.css('background-color', '');
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.